# Is there any example on how to use caliburn micro and alavon dock?

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro, avalondock

I am using caliburn micro and I want to use Avalon dock. I can not find any sample code for this and the only framework that I found is https://github.com/tgjones/gemini

Is there any better solution? with better documentation?

I am suing wpf and c# .net 4.5

Comment: https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/discussions/430994 not sure if that's any help.

Comment: Hi, this is probably too late but I'm finding similar issues so I tought it might be useful here to point to my recent SO question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28194046/correctly-handling-document-close-and-tool-hide-in-a-wpf-app-with-avalondockcal . Look in the comments for a link to a full WPF example (github), which of course is not without issues...